# Updating Redux Store from changes in child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React and learning Redux. I have a container component that has two child components. In one of the child components (Header component), I have five buttons. Its sibling component (Body component) renders different views depending on the button that's clicked in the Header component. I know I can achieve this by keeping the state in the parent component and have an event handler function that receives a call back function on click of a button, but I am trying to learn Redux for more complex apps.

To implement this, I introduced a handler function in the Parent component that dispatches an action from the data received from the call back function passed to the Header component to change the store and hence render the appropriate view from the Body component.

**Here is the Code sample:**

Parent Component:

```
...
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    selectedDS: state.selectedDS
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  changeDs: selectedDS => dispatch(changeDs(selectedDS)),
  dispatch
});

class Main extends Component {
  handleClick = button => {
    this.props.dispatch(changeDs(button));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          <div id="header" className="row">
            <Header handleClick={this.handleClick} />
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <DsComponent ds={this.props} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Main);
```

Header Component:

```
...
export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="mx-auto">
        <Navbar>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem>
              <Button className="number" onClick={() => props.handleClick(0)}>
                Number
              </Button>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <Button className="array" onClick={() => props.handleClick(1)}>
                Array
              </Button>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <Button className="string" onClick={() => props.handleClick(2)}>
                String
              </Button>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <Button className="tree" onClick={() => props.handleClick(3)}>
                Tree
              </Button>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <Button className="graph" onClick={() => props.handleClick(4)}>
                Graph
              </Button>
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Sorry for the length of the code, here is [link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-dust-78jfg?file=/src/components/Main.js)

**My question is:**

- What is wrong in the code?
- What is the best method to dispatch actions deeper in the component
  tree if I want the components to be dumb components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ISSUE :**

is with your `reducer`, you were setting up store value with wrong, you are setting up store value

```
var payload_ds = action.payload;
return Object.assign({}, state, { payload_ds });

// above line create json object something like this
// { selectedDS: 0 , payload_ds: { selectedDS: 4 } }
```

**SOLUTION :**

```
var payload_ds = action.payload.selectedDS;
return Object.assign({}, state, { selectedDS: payload_ds }); // <----- HERE

// OR

// as there is only one field you can also use this one
return { selectedDS: payload_ds }
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit awesome-mirzakhani-oc11h]

---

Q : What is the best method to dispatch actions deeper in the component tree if I want the components to be dumb components?

A : You can use `mapDispatchToProps` as you are passing everything as props it's still considered as dumb component.